# Using express-openid-connect and jsonwebtoken to verify on afterCallBack

Tags: node.js, error-handling, jwt, express-openid-connect

I am looking to verify the ID token on afterCallback of the auth, the issue is when the verification and has an error, Nodejs crashes when I throw and error, if I do not throw the error I am able to console.log it on the server side but I am unable to display this error to the actual client.

The code snippet below

```
app.use(
  auth({
    issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL,
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorizationParams: {
      response_type: 'code',
      scope: 'openid profile email'
    },
    authRequired: true,
    idpLogout: false,
    routes: {
      postLogoutRedirect:'/logged-out'
    },
    afterCallback: async(req, res, session) => {
      const claims = jose.JWT.decode(session.id_token); // using jose library to decode JWT
      console.log(claims);
      let options={ algorithms: ['S256'], audience: process.env.CLIENT_ID, issuer: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL, complete: true }
      jwt.verify(session.id_token, getKey, options, function (err, decoded) {
         if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          throw new Error(err) //This crashes my service and it is not caught or sent over to the client
         }
       });

    return session;
}
  })
);
```

I have tried switching between using async and sync functions , I tried to also res.send when the verification error takes place but this results in an error : Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

Answer (score 0):

Try this once I have added a try-catch block and removed the callback of `jwt.verify` process `Can't set headers after they are sent to the client` This error you are getting because you are sending the `res.send` two or more time to frontend client to avoid this always use `return`

```
app.use(
    auth({
        issuerBaseURL: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL,
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
        clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorizationParams: {
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: 'openid profile email'
        },
        authRequired: true,
        idpLogout: false,
        routes: {
            postLogoutRedirect:'/logged-out'
        },
        afterCallback: async(req, res, session) => {
            try {
                const claims = jose.JWT.decode(session.id_token); // using jose library to decode JWT
                let options={ algorithms: ['S256'], audience: process.env.CLIENT_ID, issuer: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL, complete: true }
                await jwt.verify(session.id_token, getKey, options);
                return session;
            } catch (error) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: error.message
                })
            }
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you so I have tried this but I am getting the error below instead which shows on the client side `{"success":false,"message":"verify must be called asynchronous if secret or public key is provided as a callback"}`

Comment: getKey config below ref https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa/blob/master/examples/express-demo/README.md  `const client = jwksClient({
  rateLimit: true,
  jwksRequestsPerMinute: 10, // Default value
  jwksUri: process.env.ISSUER_BASE_URL + '/pf/JWKS'
});
function async getKey(header, callback){
 await client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function(err, key) {
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    console.log(header)
    console.log(callback)
    await callback(null, signingKey);
  });
}
`